# cmd script reading from file and writing to file loses empty line

Tags: batch-file

I have a cmd batch script which:

- reads from a file line by line
- if the line matches the specified string, it outputs that line plus 2 new lines into the new tmp file
- if the line does not match the specified string, it just outputs that line to the new tmp file

This all works fine with this one exception, the input file contains empty lines, but when I open the tmp file, it lost all the empty lines.

How can I fix this?

Script:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set inputfile=C:\temp\animals.txt

set tempfile=C:\temp\animals.txt.tmp

del %tempfile%

copy /y nul %tempfile%

set find=hippo
set newline1=spider
set newline2=snake

for /f "delims=" %%l in (%inputfile%) do (
    if %%l==!find! (
        echo %find%>>%tempfile%
        echo %newline1%>>%tempfile%
        echo %newline2%>>%tempfile%
    ) else (
        echo %%l>>%tempfile%
    )
)

endlocal
```

Example input file:

```
dog


cat

monkey



hippo

lion

tiger
```

Comment: just to add to @stephan's answer below, attempting to help you create better code. inctead of doing `copy /y nul %tempfile%` just add `break` into your loop. `for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%a in ('type "%inputfile%" ^| find /v /n "" ^& break ^> "%tempfile%"') do...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following keeps empty lines:

```
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%l in ('type "%inputfile%"^|find /v /n ""') do echo(%%m
```

I'm sure, you can implement it yourself?

A `for /f` loop ignores empty lines, so the trick is to give it no empty lines. `find /n /v ""` preceedes every line with it's line number (in the format `[1]original line`), so `for /f` has something to process. We then use only the string after the first `]` (second token, `%%m` here), which is your original line.

You should also change your line

```
 if %%l==!find! (
```

to

```
 if "%%m"=="!find!" (
```

to avoid syntax errors, when `%%m` is empty. (Btw: I see no reason to not use `%find%` here)